# Why exactly does it make sense to talk about unique factorization in sense of multiplication but not in sense of addition?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Pretty basic question I've been having for a while. The fundamental theorem of arithmetic, loosely speaking, tells us that primes are the 'multiplicative' building blocks of any number . However, for addition, there isn't any such thing .. we don't have any 'additive primes' whose unique additive combinations gives any other number.

What exact property of multiplication (which addition doesn't have..) allows us to talk about the idea of primes, and decomposition into them?

Comment: Every integer is a unit under addition, but not multiplication.  Unique factorization ignores units.  We don't speak about unique factorization for rational numbers for the same reason, every non-zero rational is a unit.

Comment: My guess is that in multiplication there is a recursive property of unique factorization. With addition, the number of ways you partition 10 is not one more than the number of ways you can partition 9.

Comment: How about "powers of $2$"?

Comment: One interpretation of this would be that in the additive group every integer is a multiple of $1$. So $1$ is the only additive "prime" (that cannot be written as a sum of two smaller positive integers).

Comment: In other words: to generate the multiplicative monoid of $\Bbb{Z}$ you need all the prime numbers. The additive group, on the other hand, only needs a single generator, namely $1$.

Comment: Not unlike with $p$-adic rationals when you have a single prime $p$, and the rest of them are turned into units.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: I think you are talking about the result of localizing $\mathbb{Z}$ at $(p)$ (that is, all rationals that can be written in the form $\frac{a}{b}$ with $\gcd(p,b)=1$), rather than the $p$-adic rationals $\mathbb{Q}_p$, the field of fractions of the $p$-adic integers?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Correct. Past midnight here. I do think I have called $\Bbb{Q}\cap \Bbb{Z}_p$ the ring of $p$-adic rationals even though it obvious should be called "rational $p$-adic integers" or some such. As you pointed out, describing it as a localization of $\Bbb{Z}$ is unambiguous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We *do* have a "Fundamental Theorem of Additive Arithmetic" (in fact, two versions depending on how you try to mimic it). It's just that it is (they are) utterly uninteresting.

One way, restricting multiplication to positive integers, and addition to nonnegative integers.

A prime is a positive integer with the property that (i) it is not the multiplicative identity; and (ii) whenever you write it a product of two positive integers, one of the factors is the multiplicative identity.

By analogy, let us then define an *additive prime* to be a nonnegative integer with the property that (i) it is not the additive identity (not equal to $0$); and (ii) whenever you express it as a sum of two nonnegative integers, one of the summands must be the additive identity.

**Theorem.** The only "additive prime" is $1$.

*Proof.* If $a,b\geq 0$ and $a+b=1$, then either $a=0$ or $b=0$; since we also have that $1\neq 0$, this means that $1$ is indeed an "additive prime."

Now assume that $k\neq 0$, $k\neq 1$. Then $k\gt 1$; thus, $(k-1)+1 = k$ is an expression of $k$ as a sum of two nonnegative integers, neither of them equal to $0$; thus, $k$ is not an "additive prime". Hence, $1$ is the only "additive prime". $\Box$

**"Fundamental Theorem of Additive Arithmetic"** Every positive integer can be expressed in exactly one way as a sum of "additive primes".

*Proof.* If $k\geq 1$, then it can be expressed as $k=\sum_{i=1}^k 1$. By induction on $\min(r,s)$ it is easy to verify that $\sum_{i=1}^s 1 = \sum_{i=1}^r 1$ implies $r=s$, so that the expression is unique. $\Box$

True, but boring and mostly useless! It just codifies the usual order of nonnegative integers.

---

Second way: allowing positives and negative and "associates".

Multiplicatively: an integer is a "unit" if and only if it has a multiplicative inverse. A nonzero integer $k$ is a prime if and only if (i) it is **not** a unit; and (ii) whenever we express $k$ as a product, $k=rs$, either $r$ is a unit or $s$ is a unit.

Then the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic says that every nonzero integer can be written as a product of prime in a unique way **up to unit factors** and up to order.

"Unit" already has a meaning, so let us say an integer $k$ is "additively invertible" if there exists an integer $m$ such that $k+m=0$.

Let us say an integer $k$ is an "additive prime" if and only if (i) it is **not** additively invertible; and (ii) whenever we express $k$ as a sum, $k=r+s$, either $r$ is additively invertible or $s$ is additively invertible.

But then *every* integer is additively invertible, so there are no "additive primes", and the "Fundamental Theorem of Additive Arithmetic" can still be stated, but that clause of "up to additively invertible summands" make it useless, because it then says that you can express any integer as a sum of an additively invertible summand and additive primes in a unique way; but that "sum of additive primes" has no summands, so it equals zero, and all you are saying is that you can write any integer $k$ uniquely as $k=k+0$. Which, again, true, but both boring and useless.